# Using go_router push and pop a page causes rebuild, how to prevent?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I'm using go_*router to navigate between screens unfortunately it causes every time rebuilds on the current page and the page I navigate to. On most pages I read documents from Firebase which causes unnecessary reads. As alternative I use the Navigator to achive navigating between pages without rebuilds. Is it possible to achive the same effect with go_*router?

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen(),); (rebuild on screen2)
context.go("/secondScreen") (rebuilds on screen1 and screen2)
```

Instead of go_router I would use Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I believe. When I use `context.push()` or `context.pop()` all the pages' states in the stack tree were running again which caused to lose states of pages that already exist. What I realized is the difference between **pageBuilder** & **builder** methods. In order to use pageBuilder method, you need to call `MaterialPage<void>` which will build the page each time.

**Solution:**
Using `builder`  attinstead `pageBuilder`

Instead of using pageBuilder;

```
GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        pageBuilder: (context, state) => MaterialPage<void>(
          key: ValueKey<String>(state.fullPath! +
              DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()),
          child: HomePage(),
        ),
      ),
```

Use builder;

```
GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (context, state) {
          return HomePage();
        },
      ),
```

Comment: So does using `builder` instead of `pageBuilder` rebuild the widget?

Answer (score 0):

I used this package [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route).