Flutter x GoRouter: context.pop() is rebuilding the previous page?
I'm running into an issue where when I attempt to go "back" via Navigator.pop(context) or Navigator.of(context).pop, the previous page attempts to rebuild in GoRouter, causing an error because I'm not passing in the required parameters. I thought flutter navigation kept the build/state of previous pages... not having that defeats the entire point of the nav stack.
i.e., consider this route setup, where the user opens the app to LandingPage(), then clicks a button which navs to InnerPage() with the "necessaryParam." Then, from InnerPage, they route to InnerPage2(), where they click a "back" button that triggers something to the effect of Navigator.pop(context). This routes the user back to InnerPage(), but throws an exception because "necessaryParam" isn't passed.
Why is it rebuilding instead of popping InnerPage2() off the nav stack? Is the nav stack just a stack of routes to rebuild on pop()? I remember it saving state, though, so that doesn't seem right. Any insight would be much appreciated.
I realize a solution would be to just brute force repass the params from InnerPage2 using context.goNamed("inner", extra: paramObject) instead of Navigator.pop(context), but if the nav stack is maintained, this would be a very a clumsy and inefficient approach as the nav stack would just continue to grow indefinitely, which seems very wrong.
routes: <RouteBase>[
  GoRoute(
    path: '/landing',
    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
        LandingPage(),
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
        path: 'inner',
        name: 'inner',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state){
          // extract params from state.extra
          ParamObject? params = state.extra != null ? state.extra as ParamObject : null;
          var necessaryParam = params?.variable
          if(necessaryParam != null)
          {
            return InnerPage(param: necessaryParam);
          }
          else{
            throw Exception("necessaryParam missing!");
          },
        routes: <RouteBase>[
          GoRoute(
            path: 'inner2',
            name: 'inner2',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state){
              return InnerPage2();
            },
          ),
        ]
      ),
    ],
  ),
],

EDIT: I just explored this a bit with a separate route without any parameters. State is saved when routing (i.e.) change state on InnerPage, route to InnerPage2, context.pop() and state of InnerPage isn't reset. Interestingly, I threw a print statement in the GoRouter builder of InnerPage and it not only triggers on the "back" press from InnerPage2, but also when routing from InnerPage to InnerPage2.

Similar question here, still unresolved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75960397/using-go-router-push-and-pop-a-page-causes-rebuild-how-to-prevent

in your case, i would like to made a provider, to store the data inside of it from the innerPage2, and used the popUntil to go back to the LandingPage, and use the provider to call the data at the LandingPage

It seems like GoRouter rebuilds on context.pop() but restores state, so an easy enough solution is to make the parameters optional and store them in state variables like so:
// inside Widget build of InnerPage(), assuming param is an optional parameter

ValueNotifier<String> necessaryParamState = useState("");

if(necessaryParam!= null){
  // on initial routing, won't trigger on context.pop()
  necessaryParamState.value = param
}


the GoRouter builder should look something like:

builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state){
  // extract params from state.extra
  ParamObject? params = state.extra != null ? state.extra as ParamObject : null;
  var? necessaryParam = params?.variable

  if(necessaryParam != null)
  {
    // on press from previous page, pass relevant parameters for state init
    return InnerPage(
      param: necessaryParam
    );
  }
  else{
    // on "back" press from InnerPage2, parameters are loaded from state
    return InnerPage();
  }
},

Ofc this isn't perfect, but it seems like it'd work. Would love to see a cleaner solution if anybody knows one.
